# how do I host my webpage in localhost on my Mac?

Tags: html, iphone, safari, localhost, hosting

I am working on a webpage & I would like to see how it renders on my iPhone's safari browser. Rather than officially purchasing a domain & hosting, because its in the development stage I just want to view it on mobile safari temporarily.

So far I have enabled Web Sharing:

[image]

and when i type in my IP address in my iPhone's safari, the localhost seems to be up:
[image]

I have also re-created the "sites" folder:
[image]

So How do I host the current webpage i am working on with localhost, then being able to access it on mobile safari? ***NOTE I want both the html and css files to be accessed to show a complete webpage**

Comment: Try `http://IPADDRESS/~macbookair1/` (assuming mod_userdir is enabled).

Comment: in Chrome you can download UA spoofer.

Comment: @FelipeAlarcon Presumably they want to test the actual rendering, not just fake a user agent.

Comment: yeah i just want to see my webpage in mobile safari @AlexanderO'Mara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider downloading and installing [Prepos](https://prepros.io) and you'll be able to view your website in any device connected to the same network.

It's easy to use and the trial version never expires!

After installing it to your Mac, just drag and drop the site root folder into Prepos. There's a tab where you can see the http path to view in any device: TV, tablet, smartphone or any device with internet access. The only requirement is that they must be connect to the same network.

Comment: cool this works, however the root folder of the site has a few html files in there & the site i want to view isn't named "index.html", rather "index-second.html". Its opening the site with the regular index.. how to i get it to open the other one?

Comment: Great! Glad to have helped! Open the `index.html` then type `-second` manually in the browser. Got it? Or add a link to the other pages somewhere into your index, like `<a href="index-second.html">Second</a>` and you'll be able to navigate through them by touching the link! Happy coding! :)

Comment: yes i actually figured it out after i wrote the comment haha, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your Network Settings.
2. Then write down your IP Address.
3. Go to http://youriphere/~youruser/ in Safari or whatever browser and that's it!

Comment: I'm confused, how do i display the webaoge? & judging by the screenshots above, what is my user? .. can you write it in an example form?

Comment: You're already hosting it, correct? The files are in the sites folder? The user is who you are signed in as on your mac. When you log in your computer you sign in with a user and password (if you have one).

Comment: no i didn't put anything in the sites folder.. how should i put the file in the sites folder? i can't just drag the html file without the css because then it just shows like a plain html, not my fun designed site.

Comment: Why can't you put the css file in the sites folder is the real problem? Does it give an error when you include the css file? How are you linking the css to the html?